# Do Quarks violate the law of energy conservation?

Tags: energy-conservation, quarks

Look, I am not too knowledgeable in this area, but all I know is the following. So please bare with me.

**Idea**

Since Quarks are always in pairs and are bonded together by the Strong Force and cannot be separated. With that in mind when you do separate them, a quark pops into existence and thus the single quark that was separated has a new "partner" and they become a pair again. This means that whenever you separate quarks, you will always have a new quark coming into existence and they become a pair of quarks again. Hence quarks cannot be alone.

---

**Question**

With what I stated previously about quarks that are created from seemingly nothing, does that mean that quarks violate the law of energy conservation?

Is this true?

Comment: Why? You ***must*** pump lots of energy in trying to separate quarks and creating pairs out of nothing.  Lots. The first quantitative sketches in HEP courses deal with just how much.

Comment: Look I am no physicist and I did not know that. Maybe you can explain that pumping lots of energy into the system creates quarks?

Comment: @Poutnik How does this relate to my question? From my point of view, you added no value here.

Comment: @Compilerv2 Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark#Interacting_quarks

Comment: @Poutnik I see it now. Can you place your answer not in the comments but as an actual answer to this question? Thanks.

Comment: @AdrianHoward Thank you for the reading, I am more informed now.

Comment: Violations of the law of energy conservation will not be tolerated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Large Hadron Collider, they pumped a really lot of energy to the colliding protons. The mass of particles, that were created by the collisions was several orders bigger than mass of the original 2 colliding protons.

By pulling quarks from each other, you provide energy for new quarks, same as by accelerating protons, you provide energy for plenty of new particles.

BTW pairs of quarks make mesons. Baryons like proton and neutron are formed by quark  triplets.

See also [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark#Interacting_quarks) mentioned by @Adrian Howard.

Comment: Great! Thank you for your answer. I didn't know that you actually provided the energy to make new quarks. Looks like the law of energy conservation is safe.

Comment: Mesons are formed from quark pairs, baryons are formed from quark triplets, fermion is a lable for particles that have half integer spin (an electron is a fermion and is clearly not made of quarks, while a proton is composed of quarks). Bosons are the force carrying particles of the standard model and are not composed of quarks

Comment: Well, you are right. I was thinking in context of hadrons, made of quarks, and there mesons are bosons  and baryons are fermions. I will correct it.